# Error on Chromium ARC Compilation when configure

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, chromium, google-nativeclient, google-chrome-arc

Getting errors as below, when I follow **step 4** of the instruction from [Getting Started with ARC Open Source on Linux](https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc/+/release-39.4410.148.0/docs/getting-started-open-source.md). OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running in Hyper-V.

> UBUNTU14:~/arc$ ./configure
>   ERROR:root:While running
>   ['third_party/tools/depot_tools/third_party/gsutil/gsutil', 'cp',
>   'gs://arc-build/naclports/builds/pepper_40/python.zip',
>   '/tmp/tmpUZ0IoK/naclports-python'] ERROR:root:GSResponseError:
>   status=403, code=None, reason=Forbidden.
>
> ERROR:root:Try prodaccess, and if it does not solve the problem try rm
>   ~/.devstore_token @@@STEP_WARNINGS@@@ ERROR:root:Retrying after 9 s
>   sleeping Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/fkiller/arc/src/build/build_common.py", line 938, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/fkiller/arc/src/build/util/download_package_util.py", line 243,
>   in _download_package_with_retries
>       self._download_method(url, download_package_path)   File "/home/fkiller/arc/src/build/util/download_package_util.py", line 119,
>   in _download
>       build_common.get_gsutil_executable(), 'cp', url, destination_path])   File
>   "/home/fkiller/arc/src/build/util/download_package_util.py", line 97,
>   in execute_subprocess
>       output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, cwd=cwd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
>   line 573, in check_output
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['third_party/tools/depot_tools/third_party/gsutil/gsutil', 'cp',
>   'gs://arc-build/naclports/builds/pepper_40/python.zip',
>   '/tmp/tmpUZ0IoK/naclports-python']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Any idea to resolve this without changing build script? I may manually pointing python.zip from other sources such as https://naclports.storage.googleapis.com/builds/pepper_40/trunk-147-g49eb4c9/publish/python/pnacl/python.zip, but I want to build it as is without changing scripts.

I've already tried to setup gsutil and its authenticator, but it didn't fix the issue.

**EDIT:** After @elijah-taylor fixed ACL, now I'm getting errors below

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "src/build/configure.py",
>   line 365, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "src/build/configure.py", line 347, in main
>       _gclient_sync_third_party()   File "src/build/configure.py", line 132, in _gclient_sync_third_party
>       subprocess.check_output(cmd, cwd=os.path.dirname(gclient_filename))   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
>       process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

In the line 132,

```
  File "src/build/configure.py", line 132, in _gclient_sync_third_party
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, cwd=os.path.dirname(gclient_filename))
```

gclient_filename is "third_party/.gclient" and os.path.dirname(gclient_filename) is "thrid_party".

Comment: Did you try `rm ~/.devstore_token`? This works fine for me: `~depot_tools/third_party/gsutil/gsutil cp gs://arc-build/naclports/builds/pepper_40/python.zip foo.zip`.

Comment: I got `rm: cannot remove '/home/xxx/.devstore_token': No such file or directory`

Comment: I suspect the ACLs may be set up wrong, looking into it...

Comment: I believe I've fixed the ACLs to be publicly readable for that file, please give it another try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was bad ACLs on the files. I reached out to @elijah-taylor for a fix, it should now work!

Comment: Thank you. Still I don't see any updates on git https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc/+/master but I'll keep checking it to be fixed.

Comment: I got another error. Please, review my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue..fixed after running the following.

```
apt-get install gsutil
apt-get install libwww-perl
chmod +x ./third_party/tools/depot_tools/third_party/gsutil/gsutil
```